# Axis2 AxisFault Internal error

Tags: java, apache-axis

I am using axis2 web service in windows system, Eclipse Juno, Tomcat 6.0.37. I get the below error, Kindly guide me to find why this error come

> org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the
>   error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from
>   ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the  configuration
>   behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information
>   back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET
>   Framework 3.0 SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.
>         at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:446)
>         at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:371)
>         at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:417)
>         at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
>         at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
>         at org.cmc.er.GenericService.GenericServiceStub.checkDuplicateCustomer(GenericServiceStub.java:2446)
>         at com.uniphore.genericservice.CheckDuplicateCustomer.checkDuplicateCustomer(CheckDuplicateCustomer.java:40)
>         at org.apache.jsp.CheckDuplicateCustomer_jsp._jspService(CheckDuplicateCustomer_jsp.java:75)
>         at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
>         at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
>         at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
>         at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
>         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>         at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>         at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
>         at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
>         at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
>         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Is this stacktrace from WS client or WS itself ?

Comment: Thanks for your replay @Santosh, it is from WS Client

Comment: Check the server side logs. There is some error on the server side which is not clearly reported in the error response.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, The issue is in server side but not in client side, now it get resolved, thanks again.